# UIScrollView behaves different depending on fullscreen or not?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

When applying auto layout constraints to a UIScrollView, i´m given an error message if the scroll view is laid out to be full screen, but not if it has "margins". I´ll illustrate with 2 examples. In both examples i apply leading and trailing space to the superview and add top and bottom space to layout guide.

### Example 1 (behaves as i expect.)

The auto layout constraints are blue, everything is in order

[image]

### Example 2 (weird behaviour)

I stretch out the scroll view and apply the same rules as in example 1, but now 1 of the constraints ends up different. The "top space to top layout guide" is added as "Vertical space - (-548) - Top layout guide - Scroll View".
And then Xcode complains that i need "constraints for y position or height" for my scroll view.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think this is a bug in Interface Builder in Xcode 5. When you try creating a constraint from the top of a view to the top layout guide, IB usually (incorrectly) adds a constraint from the *bottom* of the view to the top layout guide.

To get around this, try first resizing the scrollView so the top edge of it is much lower down in your viewController:

[image: A ViewController containing a ScrollView, which is positioned to fill the bottom half of the ViewController]

Then try ctrl dragging from the scrollView to the viewController, and adding a constraint to the top layout guide. You can then select this constraint and adjust the constant in the inspector so that the scrollView aligns with the top of your viewController:

[image: A ViewController in Interface Builder with a ScrollView filling the bottom half. An AutoLayout constraint is selected connecting the top of the ScrollView to the ViewController's top layout guide]

Alternatively, create your constraints in code :)

Comment: This is the right solution. Please accept it! and btw you also could add your scrollview with IB and perform "resets to suggested constraints". That way your constraints are created the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the scroll view and manually create constraints for the top, left, bottom, and right edges.

What is happening here is that the automatically created constraints don't make sense, in that they do not fully define the size of the scroll view, only its position.

Answer (score 0):

Following your original example with the scrollview smaller than the containing view I noticed that XCode was actually adding one of the constraints wrong in my case, when I selected "Top space to top layout guide" it was adding a "Bottom space to top layout guide" constraint with a large negative value.  I can see something similar from your second screenshot.

My solution was to follow your example with the UIScrollView smaller than its container.  I then manually dragged out the constraints, resized the UIScrollView to fit the container.  The final step was to take the now correct constraints with the wrong constants and set them all to be 0.

Hope that helps, I'm still working on fixing the problem I had but I noticed this stage was similar to what you posted.